# Using devise to authenticate a API login request via JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rails-api

I'm trying to use devise to authenticate a simple email/password login so users can access the rest of the API via auth tokens. I'm running into trouble with devise simply returning `You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.` Here's my code:

```
class LoginController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def login
    resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
    render :status => 200,
          :json => { :success => true,
                  :info => "Logged in",
                  :user => current_user
       }
  end

  def failure
    render :status => 401,
       :json => { :success => false,
                  :info => "Login Failed",
                  :data => {} }
  end

  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
 end
```

#### routes.rb

```
  devise_scope :user do
    post 'register' => 'registration#create', :as => :registers
    post 'login' => 'login#login', :as => :login
  end
```

I'm sending the following post data:

```
{ 
  "user" : {
    "email" : "testPost4@fake.com",
    "password" : "Password1"
  }
}
```

Having browsed various posts I've added:

```
config.navigational_formats = [:json]
```

to the devise.rb file but it didn't solve the problem.

Adding `skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!` doesn't work either.

Comment: take a look at http://provoost.tumblr.com/post/80873086965/json-api-authentication-using-devise-tokens 

and here is a github https://github.com/Sjors/devise-token-api-demo

Comment: Thanks, I don't see anything relevant to the problem at hand in that post however.

Comment: Can you elaborate about the problem more? I have done something similar but I have used a sessions controller to handle the login. If you want I can post it as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to get this working so I have reverted to the much simpler approach of checking and signing in manually.

```
def login
  params = login_params
  user = User.find_by_email(params['email'].downcase)
  if user.valid_password?(params['password']) then
    sign_in(user)
    success
  else
    failure
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me out a lot!